# Generate fresh django CSRF token on each login

Tags: javascript, django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I want my websites login form to have a new CSRF token generated everytime the page is refreshed.

I tried calling

```
logout(request)
request.session.flush()
```

But the hidden form field always has the same token, even after server restart.

This obviously means that django is reading the data from the cookie. 
How do I make it such that it ignores the cookies and generates a fresh one?

Alternatively is there a way for me to have an intermediate page that clears all cookies before going to the actual login page? How does one delete all cookies for my domain in Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually reset the token as follows:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key

request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _get_new_csrf_key()
```

In Django >= 1.6, you should instead use `django.middleware.csrf.rotate_token(request)`, which does exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the `CSRF_COOKIE_AGE=None` to use session-based CSRF cookies, which keep the cookies in-memory instead of on persistent storage. I guess the CSRF token should then change if you logout a user. [See the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-age)

Comment: Thanks for that prompt reply....

Unfortunately I cannot use this, since we use a CentOS long term release server that has django 1.4 and cant be upgraded.

Is there another solution?

Comment: You could create your own CSRF middleware sub-class by extending  `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and overwrite the `process_response` method. There you can set the `max_age` of `set_cookie` to `None`.  Then just specify your middleware class in your settings.py

Comment: Thanks - for now I am using @knbks approach even if a bit hackish... 

In a few months we will switch to Ubuntu 14, and I will use the CSRF_COOKIE_AGE setting.